# how to save properties file in liferay

Tags: java, liferay

I need the properties changes made programatically to persist a server reboot, redeployment, ect.  Basically, I need modify the properties file when changes are made.  Is this even possible?  Currently, I have the properties working but the values dont ever change in the properties folder.

```
            String realPath = getPortletContext().getRealPath("/");

        FileInputStream in = new  FileInputStream(realPath+"json.properties");



        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.load(in);

        System.out.println(p.getProperty("json"));

              in.close();
        p.setProperty("json", "test");
        System.out.println(p.getProperty("json"));

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(realPath+"json.properties");
        p.store(out, "test");
        in.close();

       out.close(); 

       System.out.println(com.liferay.util.portlet.PortletProps.get("json"));
       com.liferay.util.portlet.PortletProps.set("json", "change");
       com.liferay.util.portlet.PortletProps.set("new", "change");
       System.out.println(com.liferay.util.portlet.PortletProps.get("new"));
```

portal.properties:

```
json=help
new=new1
```

json.properties

```
json=blank
```

output when code is ran:

blank
   test
   help
   change

As you can see above, I have tried using regular java properties and tried using the liferay properties.  I need to basically need to get some json, edit it, then save it for later use.  I need the changes to persist until edited again.

Comment: of course this is possible: Any program can write files and read them. However, if you tell us what problem this shall solve for you, we might give you a hint if this is good practice or if you can solve your problem more easily - e.g. like you stated in the one answer that's currently available - through PortletPreferences. (and, of course, there are other possibilities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of my previous code is junk the way I solved it was to use

```
            PortletPreferences portletPreference = actionRequest.getPreferences();

        portletPreference.setValue("help", "me");
        portletPreference.store();
```

Note: I tried this before with no luck and the problem was my imports. make sure that you use 
javax.portlet.PortletPreferences; and not the liferay portletpreferences class.